# how to add a text on a button from an string array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am making a quiz app that gives an user four options to select from.I created a string array for each options.Now I wish to set the text from the string array on the button.I have written the code but when I ran it on the Emulator it just shows the question and not the options button. Please help! I am a beginner.

```
public class question1 extends AppCompatActivity {

private int Question_no;
private Boolean Boolean_Var;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);

    String[] Question_Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Question1);
    TextView Questions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question);
    Questions.setText(Question_Array[Question_no]);

    String[] Option1_Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Option_1);
    Button Option1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Option1);
    Option1.setText(Option1_Array[Question_no]);

    String[] Option2_Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Option_2);
    Button Option2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Option2);
    Option2.setText(Option2_Array[Question_no]);

    String[] Option3_Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Option_3);
    Button Option3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Option3);
    Option3.setText(Option3_Array[Question_no]);

    String[] Option4_Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Option_4);
    Button Option4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Option4);
    Option4.setText(Option4_Array[Question_no]);

    findViewById(R.id.Menu_Button).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.Next_Button).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
```

> Layout.xml

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Option1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Question"
    android:onClick="On_Option1_Click"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Option2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Option1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Question"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Option3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Option1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Option1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Option1"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Option4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Option2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Option2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Option3"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Menu_Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Option3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Option3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Option3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="MENU" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Next_Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Menu_Button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Question"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="NEXT" />
```

> Strings.xml

```
<string-array name="Question1">
    <item> which of the foll. is a non-metal that remains liquid at room temp? </item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Option_1">
    <item>Phosphorous</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Option_2">
    <item>Bromine</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Option_3">
    <item>Chlorine</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Option_4">
    <item>Helium</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Answer1">
    <item>Bromine</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: why you created so many arrays?? A single array itself contains all your string values,  so you have to use only one..  and you can apply it in for loop according to the length of array

Comment: You should try to log the text you set to the buttons to see whether you can get the string array correctly. If the texts are confirmed correct, then make sure the layout you used is correct so that all the UI in the view is visible.

Comment: We don't have your layout file, so how do we know what you are or aren't  seeing?

Comment: @stuti kasliwal I think that would make it more complicated.But I am open to suggestions, If you are willing to explain it more clearly. Thankyou!

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added the Layout and the Strings file.Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why do you need string resources?

Comment: @cricket_007 Well that's the only method I knew.It worked for the TextView and I thought I would work for the button as well.But :( Can you please help me out?

Comment: It does work for buttons. The Button class extends the TextView class... Let me rephrase - why do you need to use XML resources at all for the strings? A [mcve] would simply use a `String[]`

Comment: Instead of using more than one arrays for the options use only one string array, something like 
`<string-array name="Option_1">
    <item>Phosphorous</item>
   .............................................
</string-array>`

.And same for the array in the java file. use one array to get the options and using `arr[1],arr[2]` you can access the values stored in it.

Comment: hey alok.. let me explain to you what I was trying to say, I am suggesting that simply make an array name "question" (or anything that you like) and add items one by one like example: `<string-array name="Question1">` with items as:  `<item> which of the foll. is a non-metal that remains liquid at room temp? </item>  <item>Phosphorous</item> .....<item>Bromine</item>` like this, automatically from indexing 0 to 5 your array will get complete and you can access any of the value by single array, the advantage is You won't need to make multiple array

Answer (score 0):

OK, so as I couldn't see your layout or strings xml file, it was impossible to pinpoint your problem. However, I've written and tested this for you, and it works. I haven't quite kept to your exact implementation, but it's not far off, and hopefully, it'll help your learning to read and follow this code through. I'm not saying this is the best way to do it by any means, and I have literally just hacked it together in an hour or so, but it works, and it's not strikingly ugly :-)

strings.xml:

```
    <resources>
        <string name="app_name">AndroidApp</string>
        <string-array name="questions">
            <item>(1) Which is your favourite of these colours?</item>
            <item>(2) Which is your favourite of these animals?</item>
        </string-array>
        <string-array name="firstOptions">
            <item>Blue</item>
            <item>Red</item>
            <item>Yellow</item>
            <item>Green</item>
        </string-array>
        <string-array name="secondOptions">
            <item>Dog</item>
            <item>Cat</item>
            <item>Gerbil</item>
            <item>Bearded Dragon</item>
        </string-array>
    </resources>
```

layout.xml:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.apps.radley.mike.androidapp.MainActivity">

         <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Placeholder"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/questionView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1" />

        <Button
    android:id="@+id/firstButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4" />

        <Button
    android:id="@+id/secondButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

        <Button
    android:id="@+id/thirdButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

        <Button
    android:id="@+id/fourthButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.Java:

```
    package com.apps.radley.mike.androidapp;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private int questionIndex;

        private List<Button> buttons;

        private List<List<String>> options;

        private List<String> theQuestions;
        private List<String> firstOptionList;
        private List<String> secondOptionList;

        private StringBuilder answers;

        private TextView questionView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            initVariables();
            initButtons();
            initOptions();
            updateView();
        }

        private void initVariables() {
            questionIndex = 0;
            buttons = new ArrayList<>();
            options = new ArrayList<>();
            theQuestions = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions));
            firstOptionList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.firstOptions));
            secondOptionList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.secondOptions));
            answers = new StringBuilder("Answers: ");
            questionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionView);
        }

        private void initOptions() {
            options.add(firstOptionList);
            options.add(secondOptionList);
        }

        private void updateView() {
            questionView.setText(theQuestions.get(questionIndex));
            setButtonText();
        }

        private void setButtonText() {
            for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
                buttons.get(i).setText(options.get(questionIndex).get(i));
            }
        }

        private void initButtons() {
            buttons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.firstButton));
            buttons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.secondButton));
            buttons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.thirdButton));
            buttons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.fourthButton));
        }

        private void showFinalView() {
            questionView.setText(answers.toString());
            for (Button button : buttons) {
                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        public void buttonClicked(View aView){
            answers.append(((Button) aView).getText());
            answers.append("; ");
            if (questionIndex < 1) {
                questionIndex += 1;
                updateView();
            } else {
                // We've run out of questions so...
                showFinalView();
            }
        }
    }
```

If you check what you've got and compare it to this, and/or run this and have a play with it and manipulate it for your own goals, I reckon you'll be able to get out of your current quandry. Have fun and happy learning :-)

EDIT: I've also run your code. Your code does work. It's just your buttons are all laid out on top of each other, because you haven't set their constraints. Change your layout file to the following, and you will see:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/Option1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Question"
    android:onClick="On_Option1_Click"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/Option2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Option1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Question"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/Option3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Option1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Option1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Option1"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/Option4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Option2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Option2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Option3"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/Menu_Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Option3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Option3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Option3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="MENU" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/Next_Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Menu_Button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Question"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="NEXT" />
```

That certainly works on my machine anyway :-) (Although I'd also check the layout settings properly, because I haven't really done much but copy and paste a view settings in there to get them to move into view).

Comment: While kinds words of suggestion, this is not an answer to the problem

Comment: Agreed. Should have put it in a comment. I'd move it if I could figure out how to do it on the App... :-/

Comment: @ Mike Radley I have got used to it :) But I will look up to your advice. For starters I edited the variables name. Have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Nice one :-) Have you solved the problem? I'm just writing something for you that I think will help further :-)

Comment: @Mike Radley nopes. Still trying to figure it out:) .Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @alokdubey Hopefully that should help (edited my answer)

Comment: @Mike Radley It would take a bit of time for me to understand your code, because of so many new terms.Thanks for giving your time.Can I ask what was wrong in the method I used?

Comment: @alokdubey What is the value of Question_no?

Comment: @alokdubey I can't see it being set that's all (and remember that array indexes start at 0 not 1) :-)

Comment: @alokdubey And what is the purpose of Boolean_Var? I can't see that being used anywhere either?

Comment: @Mike Radley The variable automatically gets initialized to 0 (As far as I know). And the Boolean variable was used for the further part of the code.

Comment: @alokdubey Ok. Well I can't immediately see a problem, so personally I'd do the following: (1) Set your Question_no int to 0 anyway at the beginning of onCreate; (2) Instead of just writing Question_Array[Question_no] in setText, add a line before where this value is placed in a String variable called, for example, buttonText. Then set the button text to buttonText. Place a breakpoint on the setText line, and run in Debug mode. When the code stops, check the value of buttonText is exactly what you expect it to be. If it's not, then at least we can see that's where the problem lies :-)

Comment: @alokdubey Problem solved. See update in my answer :-)

Comment: @Mike Radley Thanks! It worked. I used a Relative Layout. So was that an issue or it was just the constraints? Thanks! Learnt a lot from you!

Comment: @alokdubey I don't know I'm afraid. Until giving this a go yesterday, I'd never done any Android work before :-) I reckon if you search Google though, you should be able to find a free tutorial somewhere that will explain how the layouts work in more detail :-) And no problem at all. It was fun to learn a little about Android and put it immediately to some use :-)

Comment: @alokdubey And one final piece of advice... The Collections framework is such a powerful Java feature. I'd recommend putting some time into studying it (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework#). Have a good weekend :-)